# HKLM Registry key values access using WQL

Tags: registry, wmi, sccm, wql

I am trying to access an application's version using it's product code.
We can achieve above using-

```
(Get-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{EC542D5D-B608-4145-12F7-749C02B23494}').displayversion
```

where EC542D5D-B608-4145-12F7-749C02B23494  is product Code.
But I have to write it as a WMI Query (needed for SCCM). [SCUP](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55543) is not accepting this query.
There are few other mechanisms but nothing works in fetching out the version.
Example -
 1. PatchMyPC's catalog uses "path" attribute but in my case I need to fetch from Registry. So if I path as 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.......... it is giving error.

```
<bar:FileExists Path="7-Zip\7zFM.exe" Csidl="38" />
              <bar:FileVersion Path="7-Zip\7zFM.exe" Comparison="LessThan" Version="18.01.0.0" Csidl="38" />
```

So I am not able to fetch version using Registry (HKLM Unsinstall path) which is also accepted ny SCUP.

PS Win32_product class takes lot of time, so that is avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Because Win32_Product is generally a class that should be avoided SCCM introduces it's own classes for this purpose:

```
Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms
Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms64
```

It should be possible to query one of those like this

```
select Version from Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms where ProdID = '{EC542D5D-B608-4145-12F7-749C02B23494}'
```

Comment: Hi @Syberdoor, thank you for your suggestion.
The queries you have suggested do not give all the products installed.
So if I try "gwmi -class win32-addremovePrograms" or gwmi -class win32-addremovePrograms64 it is not listing all the installed products

Comment: actually they should not give all the programs installed, one should be a inventory of hklm\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall hklm\software\wow6432node\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall so they show the installed respective per machine 32bit and 64bit programs. Which one you need depends on whether you use 64bit or 32bit 7zip. I think there was also a bug years ago where the 64bit one did not work properly but it should be fixed afaik

Answer (score 0):

SCUP uses the WSUS XML Schema specifically the [BaseApplicabilityRules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/bb972749%28v%3Dvs.85%29) Schema.  You can choose any of the Types documented on that page.  They have different rules for different scenarios like WMI Query, file details, and registry queries among others. If you are looking for a version comparison from the registry the best choice would be `RegSzToVersion`.  Based on your question you would use something like

```
<bar:RegSzToVersion Key="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" Subkey="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{EC542D5D-B608-4145-12F7-749C02B23494}" Value="DisplayVersion" RegType32="false" Comparison="LessThan" Data="1.0.0.0" />
```

***Comparison*** can be any of the following values

- LessThan
- LessThanOrEqualTo
- EqualTo
- GreaterThanOrEqualTo
- GreaterThan

***RegType32*** is, by default, false so you can leave it out if you choose.  If the registry key is associated with a 32-bit entry, change that attribute to true or hardcode with the "WOW6432Node" path.

***Data*** attribute is the target version number to compare against (in standard four part version number format).